# AngularJS Route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, angularjs-ng-route

I started with AngularJS, and my route doesn't work. I searched in google and try some solution found but nothing works.

My index.html (public/index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/app.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"     src="javascript/controllers/VehiculeCtrl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Projet Web</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>-->
        <li><a href="#vehicules">Véhicules</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="">Agences</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="">Agents</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="">Statut</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
       </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <!-- div pour les templates-->
   <div ng-view>

   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js (javascript/app.js):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '../views/index.html',
        controller  : 'VehiculeCtrl'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/vehicules', {
        templateUrl : '../views/vehicules.html',
        controller  : 'VehiculeCtrl'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/agents', {
        templateUrl : '../views/vehicules.html',
        controller  : 'AgentsCtrl'
    })

                // route for the about page
    .when('/agences', {
        templateUrl : '../views/vehicules.html',
        controller  : 'AgencesCtrl'
    })

                // route for the about page
    .when('/status', {
        templateUrl : '../views/vehicules.html',
        controller  : 'StatusCtrl'
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

And my controller (controllers/VehiculesCtrl.js):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('VehiculeCtrl', function ($scope,$http, VehiculesGet) {    

    $scope.text = 'Salut ! je teste le controleur';
    var url = '127.0.0.1:3000/vehicules';
    //console.log("curieux", VehiculesGet);
    var res = VehiculesGet.getAllVehicules(url, function(data, status){
        console.log("test",status);
        console.log("test",data);
        $scope.result = data;
    });
});

// GET ALL VEHICULE
myApp.factory('VehiculesGet', [ '$http', function($http) {
    //var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/vehicules';
    var result;
    var data;
    return {
        getAllVehicules: function(url, callback) {
            $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/vehicules')
            .success(function (data, status) {
            // données récupérées avec succès
                callback(data, status);

            }).error(function(data,status){
                callback(data, status);
            });
        }
    };
 }]);
```

My tree:

- public

  - javascripts

    - controllers
    - VehiculesCtrl.js
    - app.js
  - views
  - index.html

Help me please :) ...... And sorry for my english x)
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, you specified ng-app and np-controller correctly in your html file?

Comment: Make sure you are including all your js files.
Also, I recommend you using this, its very good https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: yes in my index.html, i'm including my js file:      <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/controllers/VehiculeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, but as @maximusツ pointed out, I don't see ng-app anywhere in your html.

Comment: Where did you mention your <ng-view></ng-view>? It should be in the index.html.

Comment: ng-view is a <div> in my index.html, and <html ng-app="myApp"> is in my index.html

Comment: and thanks for your help. again

Comment: The `ng-app` should be on your `html` or `body` tag. Do you hav any error displayed in your console ? Would be helpful.

Comment: In my html no in my body. And no i didn't have errors in my console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add

```
<body ng-controller="VehiculeCtrl">
```

to your controller and remove

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

from your controller.

Then export your controller from app.js like

```
myApp.controller('VehiculeCtrl', function ($scope,$http, VehiculesGet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the angular-route after the angular, not after your controller, this should work

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/app.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/controllers/VehiculeCtrl.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])` from VehiculesCtrl.js. In VehiculesCtrl.js you should use myApp variable which is declared in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ng-view element in your markup. This is where the routing functionality places the templateUrl content. See this link for documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView